# Ambiguous [scan] tag. Burninate or cleanup?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scan) tag currently has 570 questions, and no wiki. It's being used for barcode scanning, scanners, scanning for text in CLI applications and whatnot. Should we try to define what to use it for and clean up the questions that doensn't fit the definition, or try and remove it altogether.

As it is now, it's not very useful.

Comment: It's probably best if we try to define what to use it for, as it has 570 questions, questions which other people may or may not have, putting it under a 'scan' tag makes it easy to find for the people looking for said tag, it's meaning and use is clear, it just hasn't been defined, so it's best if we define it.

Comment: @Gerwin how can you say that is "clear" when it isn't "defined" what should be used for?

Comment: As far as I can see, this tag is being used broadly. It's hard to decide which use should have precedence, and which questions should be merged to other tags. So far I've seen the use of the tag for scanning with physical scanners, barcode scanning, wifi/bluetooth scanning, network/port scanning, the ruby String.scan, C's scanf, tree scanning, DB scanning, file scanning, file system scannin, etc. ad nauseam.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've done the very exciting job of categorising the latest 100 questions using the [scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scan) tag, and this is what I got:

```
Database                15
Physical scanner/TWAIN  14
regex/text              12
Barcode/QR              11
Scanf                   11
File                    11
Other                   10
Port/network            7
Wifi/Bluetooth          5
Tree/node structures    3
Filesystem              2
```

As you can see, the use is pretty evenly distributed among the 7 most popular subjects. In the database section, there was an overweight of questions regarding HBase. The regex/text part had a lot of questions regarding Ruby's `scan()` metod. Barcode and QR scanners were mostly iOS and Android, as were Wifi and Bluetooth. The "other" bag was mostly obscure and/or clearly mistagged questions.

Mostly all the questions had relevant tags that could help them being identified without using the [scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scan) tag. In my search I also found that the top answerers and question makers only had 1, or 2 answers and questions, so it's clearly that none is to be considered an expert in this field. I also came across the [scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scanning) tag (currently 213 questions) which has a lot of similar questions.

I have thus the following proposal:

1. All questions regarding physical scanning, and image manipulation in combination with scanning is retagged to [scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scanning). The [scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scanning) wiki is updated to explicitly contain related questions.
2. We create a new tag, [database-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-scan) and retag the relevant questions to that.
3. We create a new tag, [network-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-scan) and retag questions related to networking, ports, Wifi and Bluetooth to that.
4. We burninate the [scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scan) tag.

This should cover about 50% of the current questions tagged as [scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scan) and I suspect a similar percentage of the [scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scanning) tagged questions. Of the remaining questions, about 20% of them are tagged with scan simply because they use a function called something like scan. And when we remove all the questions that are clearly wrongly tagged, I think the remainder will make it clear that this tag doesn't deserve to live.

Could I have some yays, nays or general opinions on this?

## Update

The [scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scan) tag has now been burninated, so as long as nobody tags more questions in the next 24 hours, it should be gone and away. I also got rid of the [network-scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-scanner) tag along the way since it was basically the same as [network-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-scan) but with fewer questions.

Thanks to everyone who pitched in. I've edited more questions than I want to think about, but it was probably worth it or whatever.

Comment: I like this proposal.

Comment: Yep, breaking out the sushi knife and let's separate everything.

Comment: I'm *amazed* at how hardworking and dutiful people in this community are. Simply amazed. I will never understand why you read a 100 questions tagged [scan] but I'm glad you did, and that all the other citizens here are fighting to keep our backyard clean. Thank you. PS: Please don't flag this as "too chatty".

Comment: Thanks for the cheering, guys. Makes it worthwhile :) I edited just shy of 100 questions tagged [tag:scanning], so now that tag is freed up and ready to be populated with [tag:scan] questions. I also created the [network-scan] and [database-scan] tags. I also don't understand why I do this.

Comment: "and retag questions related to networking, ports, Wifi and Bluetooth to that." I don't think that's on-topic for SO...

Comment: There is also a port-scanning tag

Comment: @ArjunShankar  I've done it twice; it's especially hard if you do it right and fix everything not just the tag.  Cleaning out a large dumpster tag is harder work but more beneficial in improving the quality of the site than most other forms of cleanup. IMO all long term users should do it once just to see how much work goes into making it not suck.  Unfortunately, unlike doing 1k review audits there's no badge to encourage it; and I can't think of any possible way to award one that wouldn't end up being abused by increasing the flood of crappy retag-only edits the site already suffers from.

Comment: `Physical scanner/TWAIN` is my understanding of what it should be used for. As in "can you scan this for me?"

Comment: _It's still alive!_ I just retagged the new question.